# Break in classic ASP page

Tags: javascript, sql, asp-classic

I'm working on a webpage where it gets its data from a SQL database. And I want to break the records so that when it reaches the third row, it will break to another page. 
I have a javacript in order for it to break page. However, this records are displayed in a table. And I don't know how to place  in the code. Any suggestion? 
Thanks.

`<style>div.break {page-break-before:always}</style>`

```
Sub DisplayRecords()
    Do until registerRS.eof
        counter=counter+1
        if counter=41 then
            counter=0
            counter=counter+1
        end if
        r = r + 1
        If r = 1 then
            Response.write "<tr>"
        End if
        %>
    <td>
    <%=registerRS.Fields("SchoolId")%> <br />
    Class: <%=registerRS.Fields("class")%><br />
    </td>   
        <%
        If r = 2 then
            Response.write "</tr>"
        End if

        If r = 3 then r = 1
        registerRS.movenext
    loop
    registerRS.close
    set registerRS=nothing 
End sub
```

Comment: A note on tagging...don't use 'asp'. It is ambiguous and depreciated. Please use the asp-classic tag in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to apply that style to a table row. From looking at your code I'm assuming you want to display 3 records per row, with a page break every three rows. If so you can do the following:

**CSS**

```
tr.break {page-break-before:always;}
```

**ASP**

```
Sub DisplayRecords()
    rowCount = 0
    Do until registerRS.eof
    counter=counter+1
    if counter=41 then
    counter=0
    counter=counter+1
    end if
    r = r + 1
    If r = 1 then
       if rowCount < 3 then
          Response.write "<tr>"
          rowCount = rowCount + 1
       else
          Response.write "<tr class='break'>"
          rowCount = 0
    End if
    %>
<td>
<%=registerRS.Fields("SchoolId")%> <br />
Class: <%=registerRS.Fields("class")%><br />                    
</td>         


    <%
    If r = 2 then
            Response.write "</tr>"
        End if

        If r = 3 then r = 1
    registerRS.movenext
    loop
    registerRS.close
    set registerRS=nothing 
    End sub
    %>
```

[This fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/np3cv/2/) shows the code in action. Print [this page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/np3cv/2/show/) to see the page break in action.

**However**

The most elegant way to do this is to use the [CSS3 nth Child Selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild). The downside is lack of browser support from older browsers and IE.

You would use something like:

```
tr:nth-child(3n +4) {page-break-before:always;}
/*3n says select every third row with + 4 being the row to start from*/
```

See [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/np3cv/3/) and print preview [this one](http://fiddle.jshell.net/np3cv/3/show/)

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code. It is not giving error but for some reason, it doesn't break at third row.

Comment: @JohnDoe4136 can you provide an example of the code a rendered to the page. Thanks.